# Send a side effect http request after a successful one using rxjs operator

Tags: angular, rxjs

My question headline may not be very clear, let me clarify more and you are welcome to improve it.

I have an angular application which polls a set of data every few seconds. Now I have a timer observable like this, and is subscribed in another place.

```js
public readonly people$ = timer(3, 10000).pipe(
  switchMap(()=> this.http.get(url).pipe(tap(()=>{
      //here is some business logic
      //then at the end here I want to send a request unrelated to main business logic flow, e.g. auditing information update`
    })
  )
)
```

I need this `people$` observable to **ONLY** return `people` at the end, but meanwhile to trigger another http request to do something else that's **unrelated** to current stream.

What I have tried:

1. Calling `http.post(anotherUrl)` inside the `tap` but obviously it won't work because it's not subscribed.

```js
public readonly people$ = timer(3, 10000).pipe(
  switchMap(()=> this.http.get(url).pipe(
    tap(()=>{
      //here is some business logic
      this.post(anotherUrl); //won't trigger as no subscription and I don't think it's good to subscribe here
    })
  )
)
```

2. Changing `tap` to `async` and calling the request with `toPromise`, like:

```js
public readonly people$ = timer(3, 10000).pipe(
  switchMap(()=> this.http.get(url).pipe(
    tap(async()=>{
      //here is some business logic
      await this.post(anotherUrl).toPromise();
    })
  )
)
```

And this can work, but I wonder what should be a proper way to do this and whether I can achieve this in a rxjs way?

Answer (score 0):

This can be simplified a bit:

```js
public readonly people$ = timer(3, 10000).pipe(
  switchMap(_ => this.http.get(url).pipe(
    tap(_ => {
      //here is some business logic
    })
  )
)
//-------------
public readonly people$ = timer(3, 10000).pipe(
  switchMap(_ => this.http.get(url)),
  tap(_ => {
    //here is some business logic
  }),
);
```

Running an observable as a side effect of another stream is very likely a code smell. Doubly since you don't seem to want the result returned by the observable.

Either way, here are two ways to do it, though neither feels like idiomatic RxJS.

```js
public readonly people$ = timer(3, 10000).pipe(
  switchMap(_ => this.http.get(url))
  tap(_ => {
    //here is some business logic
    this.post(anotherUrl).subscribe();
  })
);
//------------- Or this:
public readonly people$ = timer(3, 10000).pipe(
  switchMap(_ => this.http.get(url))
  tap(_ => {
    //here is some business logic
  }),
  mergeMap(people => this.post(anotherUrl).pipe(
    ignoreElements(),
    startWith(people)
  ))
);
```

---

#### How this should typically look:

You have three+ consumers (subscribers) of people$, so you'll want to multicast the source. There are many ways to do this, but `share`/`shareReplay` are two of the easier options.

Then in your constructor/initializer/wherever makes the most sense, you consume it separately for each side effect. You may also have a component in your UI displaying people, so it can be consumed there too.

Some things make sense in a tap operator; like logging/debugging, for example. Generally, it's probably bad (for maintenance and extendability) to start putting business logging inside a `tap` operator.

```js
public readonly people$ = timer(3, 10000).pipe(
  switchMap(_ => this.http.get(url)),
  shareReplay(1)
);

public init(): void {

  people$.subscribe(_ => {
    //here is some business logic
  });

  people$.pipe(
    mergeMap(_ => this.post(anotherUrl))
  ).subscribe();

}
```

The benefit here is that you've created a separation of concerns rather than shoving side effects that are completely orthogonal inside a single observable. Makes this easier to update and maintain.

This is especially the case if/when you want to start catching and dealing with errors.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and suggestion. May I further ask what you think is the better way to handle the side effect that fulfills my requirement?

Comment: @JunlongWang Sure, I've updated my answer